# How to use a package without style file (for "changes" package)?

Tags: packages, overleaf

I am trying to utilize ["changes" package](https://ctan.org/pkg/changes?lang=en) (on overleaf). However, when writing `\usepackage{changes}`, the compiler has the following error:

> LaTeX Error: Command \comment already defined. /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/changes/changes.sty

As I know the solution is using the package with the following option, for example:

```
\usepackage[commandnameprefix=always]{changes}
```

But, it does not solve the issue. Apparently, the problem comes from the style version of the package. Hence, I need to update the style file.

On the other hand, I cannot find the style file inside the corresponding zip file on the CTAN website to use it directly in my project. What is the solution to use the package in that case?

Comment: You are using texlive 2019 on Overleaf and probably an older version of the package. the default for new projects is texlive 2020, or you can change in the project sidebar.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @Bernard mentioned in the comments, I could find my solution by compiling `changes.ins` find in the zip file. Hence, get `.sty` file by running the following command:

```
tex changes.ins
```

Comment: that is true but changes.sty is in texlive and is on Overleaf, you just need `\usepackage{changes}` (I just tested this on overleaf)

Comment: see https://www.overleaf.com/read/kfqzgsshbhty

Comment: no it is in your project menu on overleaf, either you explicitly set it to 2019 or it is an old project that you started when texlive 2019 was the default. Either way you can choose any texlive between 2016 and 2020 in the project menu in the left sidebar on overleaf

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit late in mentioning this... but you can send Overleaf questions to support@overleaf.com (I'm on the Overleaf support team). See also: https://www.overleaf.com/blog/new-feature-select-your-tex-live-compiler-version